VBA to select a specific filter item from a pivot table created from a data model
I have a pivot table "pvt_1" created from a data model table "table1" with two filters "filter1" & "filter2" and two values "sum_of_donoughts", "sum_of_cookies". "filter1" has items "all", "item1", "item2"
I want to write a VBA subroutine to select only "item1" from "filter1".
So far I have this, but the if statement never gets executed, pf.PivotItems.Count seems to be 0:
Sub Select_Filter()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("pvt1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[table1].[filter1].[filter1]")
pf.ClearAllFilters

For Each Pi In pf.PivotItems
    If Pi.Name = "Item1" Then
        Pi.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next Pi

End Sub
Any help will be appreciated.


Are you running this code directly, or calling it from another sub/function?  And, if the latter, have you used On Error Resume Next or something, to prevent it from giving you error messages?

Before anything else, you forgot to Dim pi AS PivotItem, so you might benefit from using Option Explicit.  However, that is not (directly) one of your main issues.

Your first issue is quite simple: the Field in your PivotTable is not called "[table1].[filter1].[filter1]"; it is called "filter1".
Your second issue is… calling ClearAllFilters will select everything, not unselect it.  So, your current code will just set your Filter to "(All)".  (Because you never unselect the things you don't want)
Your third issue is… that a PivotItem doesn't have a Selected property.  (You want the Visible property.  Properly using Dim pi As PivotItem would have enabled IntelliSense, and made this easier to spot)
The final issue that you might encounter is that changing items one-by-one will cause the PivotTable to update itself with every change — unlike doing so manually in Excel, when the PivotTable will only update when you click "OK".  If you have a lot of data in your PivotTable, then this will make the macro run very slowly.  Fortunately, we can use the ManualUpdate property to control that.  (Of course, if you are only selecting one item, then you could just set the CurrentPage of the PivotField instead)
Sub Select_Filter()
    Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("pvt1")
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("filter1")
    pf.ClearAllFilters

    pt.ManualUpdate = True
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        pi.Visible = (pi.Name = "Item1")
    Next pi
    pt.ManualUpdate = False

End Sub

or
Sub Select_Filter()
    Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("pvt1")
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("filter1")
    pf.ClearAllFilters

    pf.CurrentPage = "Item1"

End Sub


You can avoid the repeated refresh of the PT, by including a check for Visible before setting the Visible flag.  That way the only time anything gets changed is when the Item is found or when an invalid item is found that is Visible.

@FrankBall pf.ClearAllFilters makes all items visible, so all invalid items would be visible, so you would still get a refresh for every item that you mark non-visible.  Removing that might reduce the number of refreshes, assuming that you already had a filter active for a single item, but you cannot guarantee that the user has left the PivotTable in that state.  You also cannot set all items to non-visible¹.  Using ManualUpdate means that it does not matter which or how many items are or are not visible, it will only refresh after the loop is complete.

¹ (The "You cannot set all items to non-visible" is the main argument to include pf.ClearAllFilters — or run two loops.  If all of your currently-visible invalid items are before your currently-invisible valid item, then the loop will throw an error when it tries to make the last invalid visible item invisible. You can bypass that with two loops, if your first loop is "should this item be made visible?", and the second loop is "should this item be made invisible?", but… that's still repeated refreshes.)

Thanks so much for your help. I tried using the second option but when I set pf = pt.PivotFields("filter1") I get an run-time error 1004 (Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PicotTable class".
If I set pf to "[Table1].[filter1].[filter1]" I do not get the error but then I get an error in pf.CurrentPage = "item1" (run-time error 1004, Unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField class).
Is my item1 name not right? I tried to print the filter items but there are none (pf.PivotItems.count = 0)

That sounds like you haven't set it as a PageField: Try Dim pf As PivotField, pt As PivotTable: For Each pt In Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables: For Each pf In pt.PivotFields: Debug.Print pt.Name & "¦" & pf.Name & "|" & pf.Orientation: Next pf, pt to confirm the names as orientations?

Thanks. I haven't set a PageField.
I ran the code that you suggested and confirmed that the name of the filtered Field is "[Table1].[filter1].[filter1]"
The pivot item seems to be called "[Table1].[filter1].&[item1]" but I am unable to set it to visible  pi.visible = True  and pi.visible = (pi.Name = "[Table1].[filter1].&[item1]". Both produce run time error.  Same pf.CurrentPage = "[Table1].[filter1].&[item1]".   :-(
Can't find what is wrong.

@CocoPalafox Looking at the image you have posted… The sheet in the picture is called "Sheet2", but all of your code references "Sheet1".  Does changing Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") to Worksheets("Sheet2") fix anything?

Hello, thanks. My pivot table is actually in Sheet1. I am able to reset the filters but not able to select a specific one. I have no idea why!

@Chronocidal, that "You cannot set all items to non-visible" and mutliple refreshes issue ate my lunch pretty badly one time, so I'm pretty diligent (or is it "paranoid") about finding ways to avoid them. I never thought about changing the "ManualUpdate" flag, which would speed up and stabilize this kind of process.

@Chronocidal, I've also used Collections to store the fields that get changed (one for Visible, one for Not Visible). Then I check the size of the collections and if it's more than one, I update the fields in the collection (Visible first, then Not Visible).  That way I'm only ever changing the Fields that need to be changed.

This seems to work. I am unsure why my PivotFields name and Items are with the [].
Sub Filter_Single_Item()
   Dim pt as PivotTable, pf As PivotField, ws As Worksheet
   
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ("Sheet1")
   Set pt = ws.PivotTables("pvt_1")
   Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[Table1].[filter1].[filter1]")

   pf.ClearAllFilters

   pf.VisibleItemsList = Array("[Table1].[filter1].&[item1]")
End Sub

